# MySQL Trigger won't work whenever I try to insert new records

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to recreate the function I created from T-SQL to MySQL and I'm having difficulties making my Trigger work.

here's what I'm supposed to do:
1. I need to create a function that will create a specialize ID based on this format:
date - 6digit code which will be the actual ID that is incremental

1. next i need to create the trigger which will call my created function to generate the ID whenever I try to insert new records.

here's what I did:

```
-- created the table first
DROP TABLE abc
Create table abc
(
    IDnumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(32)
)

-- Function
DROP FUNCTION GenerateID

 CREATE FUNCTION GenerateID (id int)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(10) 
       RETURN CONCAT(substr((cast(CURDATE() as char(10))),3,2), '-', right(concat('000000', cast( id as char(6) ) ), 6) );


-- create the Trigger

    DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER ID_Insert BEFORE INSERT ON ABC
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE abc
        SET abc.IDNumber = generateID(abc.IDNumber) ;
--     FROM abc 
--    INNER JOIN Inserted ON abc.IDNumber = inserted.IDNumber;
END

||
```

I commented out the portion --FROM abc and -- INNER JOIN part as this is the syntax I used in T-SQL. I tried to apply it here but I'm getting a syntax error. Now the trigger is created successfully, but the problem is when I now begin inserting records.

```
 insert into abc (name) values('cammie')
  insert into abc (name) values('helios')
etc
```

I'm getting error 1442 which says 'cant update table using trigger/function because it's already being used in the statement which invoked this function/sp

What do you think I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your trigger body, instead of trying to update the table already being updated, just use

```
SET NEW.IDNumber = generateID(abc.IDNumber) ;
```

Comment: ah I see now it works, though seems like my function is erroneous.